# api gateway node js gateway cant connect of database mongodb atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, api

I am using the serverless backend of aws gateway however getting a internal error in postman while connecting to mongodb atlas

https://hackernoon.com/building-a-serverless-rest-api-with-node-js-and-mongodb-2e0ed0638f47
Using the following tutorial

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
let isConnected;

module.exports = connectToDatabase = () => {
  if (isConnected) {
    console.log('=> using existing database connection');
    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  console.log('=> using new database connection');
  return mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://gaurav45@cluster0-ycxzk.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true',
{
    useNewUrlParser: true
}
)
    .then(db => { 
      isConnected = db.connections[0].readyState;
    });
};


connecting to the database to post requests
```

Comment: What's the error message you are getting

Comment: method not defined